# Does a chatroom get frozen even if feeds post messages?

Tags: support, chat

Let's say, there's a chatroom and no user is active. But, RSS/Atom feeds keep posting messages in it.

Would the chatroom get frozen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the feeds user, by posting feeds, doesn't prevent the room from being frozen or deleted for inactivity.

Once it is frozen/deleted, the feeds are no longer posted; if it is unfrozen/undeleted (can only be done by a diamond) and there were some feeds, they are being posted again.

Comment: (repro'd on an old room)